# Добавление новых XML (SVG) элементов при помощи jQuery

Tags: jquery, svg, pdf

Добрый вечер!

Я делаю [прототип конструктора визиток](http://vv.vipvizitka.in.ua/po/index2.html). Слева находятся поля формы, куда пользователи сайта будут вносить свои данные, потом нажимать на кнопку "+" рядом с полем формы. Сейчас работает только поле "Фамилия"... Допустим я заполняю в поле "Фамилия" - **"Иванов"** и нажимаю кнопку "+" рядом с полем, но на холсте SVG ничего ничего не происходит, но если теперь я внизу страницы нажимаю кнопку "Сохранить визитку", то выдает такой xml код:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?-->

<svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" width="93mm" height="53mm">
<color-profile name="acmecmyk" href="http://printers.example.com/acmecorp/model1234"></color-profile>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="93mm" height="53mm" stroke="black" stroke-width="2px" fill="white"></rect>
    <g id="square">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" fill="blue" stroke="red" stroke-width="5px" rx="8" ry="8" id="myRect" class="chart"></rect>
    </g>
    <use href="#square" transform="scale(2)"></use>
    <text x="20" y="55" font-family="Verdana" font-size="43pt" id="hello">Hello World!</text>
    <text x="100" y="100" font-family="Arial" font-size="25px" fill="#FF0000">Кукарамба</text>
    <text x="30" y="60" font-family="Verdana" font-size="20px">Иванов</text></svg>
```

Получается, что нужный элемент добавляется перед закрывающимся тегом `</svg>`. А добавляется это все с помощью вот такого кода на jQuery:

```
//Обработка событий, при нажатии на кпопки <button>+</button>
$('#fill_surname').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //Отключает кнопку + с id="fill_surname"
    var surname = $('#surname').val();
    //alert(surname); //отладка
    function fill_surname() {
        var elem = $('<text/>').attr("x", 30).attr("y", 60).attr("font-family", "Verdana").attr("font-size", "20px").text(surname);

        $('svg').append(elem);
    }
    fill_surname();
});
```

Генерируется вот такое [SVG изображение](http://vv.vipvizitka.in.ua/po/image.svg) и вот такой [PDF документ](http://vv.vipvizitka.in.ua/po/doc.pdf) из SVG изображения.

Подскажите? как мне сделать так, чтобы при вводе данных в поле **"Фамилия"** и нажатии рядом на кнопке "+" *автоматически* обновлялась картинка на холсте SVG?

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне сделать так, чтобы при вводе данных в поле формы и нажатии рядом на кнопке "+" **автоматически** обновлялась картинка на холсте SVG?

Comment: Неужели никто не знает ответ на данный вопрос и не может не чем мне помочь?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (ua.indexOf("msie") != -1 ) {
        $('#c').html($('#c').html().replace(/img/g, 'image'));
}else{
        $('#c').html($('#c').html().replace(/href/g, 'xlink:href').replace(/img/g, 'image'));
}
```

где #с-контейнер где лежит твой svg, то есть по факту ты просто перезаписываешь содержимое контейнера